# Forgot password Link to the community(via mail) returning wrong community URL?

Tags: community, sandbox

I am new to salesforce. I have a community for my users in sandbox.Community is in the preview mode.The login to the community site is working just fine, i can login to the community with the test user's credentials.The problem is when a user forgets their password and tries to reset it. It sends an email to the user with the template assigned to the Forgot Password community setting. The email template includes the {!Community_URL} merge field. Ideally the email received contains a link to the page with some type of reset token as a parameter(your_community_domain/communitiy_name/login?c=TOKEN),and it should be redirected to the change password page. But When the user clicks on the above link, it gets redirected to the link (your_community_domain/communitiy_name/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?r=some token) which redirects to login page and thus there is no way for them to reset their password. Interesting thing is as community is in preview mode ideally it should not be sending any forgot password mails, but in this case it is sending mail with wrong url.

So what should I do to fix this issue? Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that came up from their Winter 16 Release.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000IWbfAAG